# Parallel code hangs if run first, but works if run after running non-parallel code

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scikit-learn

So this sounds a bit convoluted, but I've had a problem with joblib lately where it will create a bunch of processes and then just hang there (aka, each process takes up memory, but uses no CPU time).

Here is the simplest code I've got that will reproduce the problem:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np
from sklearn import cross_validation as cval
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def fit_hanging_model(n=10000, nx=10, ny=32, ndelay=10,
                       n_cvs=5, n_jobs=None):
    # Create data
    X = np.random.randn(n, ny*ndelay)
    y = np.random.randn(n, nx)

    # Create model + CV
    model = linear_model.Ridge(alpha=1000.)
    cvest = cval.KFold(n, n_folds=n_cvs, shuffle=True)

    # Fit model
    par = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=10)
    parfunc = delayed(_fit_model_cvs)
    par(parfunc(X, y, train, test, model)
                      for i, (train, test) in enumerate(cvest))

def _fit_model_cvs(X, Y, train, test, model):
    model.fit(X, Y)  

n = 10
a = np.random.randn(n, 32) 
b = np.random.randn(32, 10)

##########
c = np.dot(a, b)
##########

fit_hanging_model(n_jobs=3)
```

Here is what happens:

- If I run all of the code above, then it spawns off three processes and hangs
- If I run all of the code above, but use n_jobs=1, then it works fine
- If I run all of the code above a second time, after running it once with n_jobs=1, then it works fine no matter how many jobs I use.
- If I run all of the code above EXCEPT for the code between the ######, then it runs fine.
- However, if I then run the code between the ######, and try to run fit_hanging_model with n_jobs > 1, then it hangs

This is with joblib = 0.8.0, and sklearn 0.15-git.

Note, this bug is on CentOS on linux. I have not been able to reproduce this bug on another machine, so it may be hard to reproduce.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be going on? It seems like that dot product is doing something strange, but I have no idea what it could be...I'm at the end of my rope...

Comment: Can you post some code to make it easier to assess?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out. Apparently this was an issue with Joblib creating multiple python processes, while MKL was simultaneously trying to do threading. See the issue and the solution (which involves setting environment variables) here:

https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/138

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience, `joblib` hangs when the function it calls makes another level of parallelization.

Using the solution in the answer by @choldgraf, you need to disable the inner level of parallelization by MKL:

```
import os
os.environ['MKL_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'
os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'
os.environ['MKL_DYNAMIC'] = 'FALSE'
```

This applies to other parallel computing libraries such as `OpenMP`.